# How can I validate a currency field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, ef-code-first

I have an ASP.NET MVC-4 application with this currency field:

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}", ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

This is the corresponding part in my view:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
```

If the price is 100 Euro the text field in the view shows:

> 100,00 €

This is nice.

But I am having problems as soon as I try to do a Postback. The validator pops up and says that the price field needs to be a number.

I can only fix this if (1) I delete the € symbol and (2) replace the decimal separator (replace comma with a dot).

If there is no better solution, I guess I could change the DataFormatString = "{0:F2}" in order to avoid the currency symbol.

But how do I make the validator accept the comma as decimal separator instead of the (American) dot?

Thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: i think you need to do a custom model binder check this link http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx

Comment: @Overmachine: Thanks for your comment. But I don't think the ModelBinder will fix the validator issue. In other words: I still want client validation - and the validator will still fail (with or without the ModelBinder), am I wrong?

Comment: the client validation will still work, the problem is when you do the post back, it's sending the currency symbol.

Comment: Hi again. What do you mean by "the client validation will still work"? Of course it will work, but the result of the validation will be negative - even when I delete the currency symbol. At least that's what happened in my test runs. Anyways, I was able to fix my problem by using the stuff from http://github.com/jquery/globalize. Thanks for your help, Overmachine!

Answer (score 1):

So, I was able to solve my problem with jQuery's Globalization plugin from http://github.com/jquery/globalize.

I added the following files to my **/scripts** folder:

- /scripts/globalize.js
- /scripts/cultures/globalize.cultures.js
- /sctipts/cultures/globalize.culture.de-DE.js

In **BundleConfig.cs**:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/globalization").Include(
          "~/Scripts/globalize*",
          "~/Scripts/cultures/globalize*"));
```

In **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts/globalization")
```

and in the script section of **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
        }
        $.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
            return this.optional(element) || (Globalize.parseFloat(value) >= param[0] && Globalize.parseFloat(value) <= param[1]);
        }
```

However, I couldn't make the currency symbol to work with the client validation, so I also changed the data annotation as follows:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:c}", ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
```

But that was it. No other changes necessary. I can now enter values like "1,49" or "18,77" and everything gets stored properly in my database.