# How to properly validate a price/currency field?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, model-validation

How can I properly validate a price field when doing postback?
I have already checked: [How can I validate a currency field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730043/how-can-i-validate-a-currency-field) but that doesn't fulfil my expectations.

I've tried with (and some variations):

```
[Range(0, (double)decimal.MaxValue)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "...")]
public decimal? Price {get; set;}
```

Problems:

- It never uses the [DataType...] attribute to perform validations.
- When the value used is not of decimal type, the issued validation error will be a standard English message that I don't know how to customize and need to.
- If I make it string instead of decimal?, then the range validation will be thrown for non-decimal or negative values, but it will still allow values like: 1.23456, which is not the currency format I'm expecting.

I'm looking for a built-in approach before I have to create my own custom validation or regular expression. Something like:

```
[EmailAddress()]
public string ContactEmail {get; set; }
```

This perfectly suits me!

Comment: What validation do you want?

Comment: Usual currency values (excluding the currency symbol). Like for example: 9.99, 0.80, 128.50. In pseudo-regex: d*[.d[d]]. Just that I don't want to have to craft it by myself if a built-in solution already exists.

Comment: Do you mean you want to limit input to only 2 decimal places? (if so you can always use a `RegularExpressionAttribute`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FluentValidation. You create your own validator class inheriting from : AbstractValidator and inside the constructor you can put all your logic.

```
MyCurrencyValidatorMyClass : AbstractValidator<MyClass>
{
    MyCurrencyValidatorMyClass()
    {
         RuleFor(x => x.MyField).NotNull().GreatherThan(0);
         //All your rules
    }
}

var validator = new MyCurrencyValidatorMyClass();
var myClassVar = new MyClass();
validator.Validate(myClassVar);
```

Also you can integrate your validator with MVC, for reference please see 
https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc

For decimal reference see
https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/Validators/ScalePrecisionValidator.cs

This is the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation

Comment: Is there an example of how to use the ScalePrecisionValidator?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher just create the instance and call the Validate method, or do the same that they do in the constructor, call the Init and then call Validate, or use it on this way as well https://github.com/MichalJankowskii/FluentValidation.Validators.UnitTestExtension/wiki/3.-Validator-verifiers#scaleprecisionvalidatorverifier

Answer (score 0):

You can try this RegEx on your `Price` model property. It will check for strings in the format of "XXXX.XX" where X is a numeric digit (0-9):

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{1,20}(\.\d{1,2})?", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Price. Please use the format of XXXX.XX.")]
```

The first range `d{1, 20}` allows up to twenty digits before the decimal place. The second range `d{1, 2}` allows up to two decimal places.